# Editor: SlickEdit vs Visual Studio Code?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I'm looking for an js editor has cross reference, can find definitions, find all references. SlickEdit is $100+, Visual Studio Code is free. Is it worth to buy slickEdit ? What're the drawbacks of Visual Studio code ? thanks !

Comment: Questions asking for nothing but opinion are off-topic here. So are questions asking us to recommend software.

Comment: I use [Atom](http://atom.io) editor. It's open source and built on Electron.

Comment: cool, heard about Atom before, let me give it a try, thanks !

Comment: Visual Studio Code is also open source, built on Electron and in my opinion performs better than Atom. I used to use Atom and it was slow on big files and crashed from time to time (haven't used it in a while though, might have gotten better).